# Having trouble writing an integral as a power series

Tags: power-series

I was given this integral:

$$\int\frac{\ln {(1-t)}}{3t}\,\mathrm dt$$

I am having trouble with writing this as a power series, and I'm not sure where to start. I know I need the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln {(1-t)}$, but I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: There should be no difficulty finding the Maclaurin series for $\ln {(1-t)}$.  Its derivative, up to sign, is just $\frac 1{1-t}$ which is the usual Geometric Series, so correct the sign and integrate that term by term.

Comment: so then what should i do to find the power series?

Comment: Go step by step.  Start with $\ln {(1-t)}$.  Then divide that by $t$.  Then integrate term by term.

Comment: @lulu so then what would the function look like? How would I set it up after I do that?

Comment: Step by step, as I say.

Comment: @lulu wait, I'm confused. So I take the derivative of $ln(1-t)$, then where would that go in the integral? Would it look like
$$\int\frac{dt}{(1-t)(3t)}$$ ?

Comment: Please go step by step.  Don't just demand the full solution at once.  I gave you a recipe for finding the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln {(1-t)}$.  Just do that first.

Comment: @lulu I got the expansion to be:

$$t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}$$

Comment: I think you are just taking that from the posted solution below (you also copied the sign error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since$$\frac1{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots,$$you have$$\log(1-t)=-\left(t+\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}3+\cdots\right)$$and therefore\begin{align}\int\frac{\log(1-t)}{3t}\,\mathrm dt&=-\frac13\int1+\frac t2+\frac{t^2}3+\cdots\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\frac13\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2^2}+\frac{t^3}{3^2}+\cdots\right).\end{align}

Comment: so does this mean that the first terms would be

$$C+\frac{-1}{3}+\frac{-4}{12}$$ etc?

Comment: @johnners17 Why are you taking $t=1$?

Comment: Well, since the series is centered at $t=0$, then would I not just continue adding one to t?

Comment: I really have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: OH I REALIZE MY MISTAKE. I thought it had to be a number value, but really it has to be in terms of $t$. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.